# The best document structure to use with Elasticsearch or other Document-oriented databases

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, nosql, nest

I have an object with some aggregates in the following structure:

[image: Project object structure]

- Each Project has about 300 components.
- Each componente has about 30 Tasks.
- And each Task could has about 20 registers.

The properties of each object are normally small texts like titles, names and float numbers.

Saving a Json file with about 10 projects, it gets about 60mb.

Saving these same 10 projects in an Elasticseach index, a simple select to get all the projects takes about 10 seconds to retrive the response, what I understand to be a long time to that scenario.

```
GET projects/project/_search?pretty=true&q
```

Knowing I really need all the properties of the objects, is there another way I could save the data in a Document-oriented solution?

Is my objects structure right for that scenario?

In the client application, these documents are normally retrieved all at once, in order to make some data analysis about the projects.

Comment: What you are expecting to do with the document later on, query it, aggregate on it or maybe just retrieve it based on id? I think, knowing your scenarios will help people understand what are you looking for with your schema design.

Comment: Hello @Rob, thank you for the reply. I have just edited the question. Normally the documents are retrieved all at once, in order to make some data analysis about the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Well generally spoken you should design a **flattened** structure for a document based database. Make yourself free of the concepts of relational databases (e.g. foreign keys, normalizations).

With that being said you should avoid the join-datatype when ever possible. In some scenarios it makes sense but it should not get too complex and nested in my opinion.

By not referencing documents (like you would in a RDBMS) you **will** get redundant information. But in the context of document based databases thats completely fine! So your lists would be arrays that contain objects (not documents) in which all the information are stored.

Lets say you only have one project with n subobjects (the lists you showed). In a completely flattened world you would have **one** document indexed.

**But as always:**

Everything depends on your specific use case. My intention was to give you some hints. I have encountered numerous times that DBA's implemented the relational model into elasticsearch and the outcome was really bad.

I would recommend to implement a basic prototype to get started with the flattened structure.

I hope I could help you!

Comment: You're completlety right. That's how I'm storing the document in ES: saying that I have one Project with N subobjects, I have ONE document indexed.

Comment: @Felipe Santana have you had any success with my proposal? If you feel satisfied I would really appreciate an upvote/acceptance of my answer. Thanks.